# Calculate dollars to millions returns integer

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to calculate dollar amount (in DB as Decimal(15, 0) NOT NULL) to millions by dividing but as result I get only integer amount.

desired result:

```
AMOUNT    AMOUNT IN MIL
123000    0.1
1123000   1.123
```

I have this, but it return only 0, 1...

```
SELECT ... AMOUNT / 1000000 AS "AMOUNT IN MIL" FROM ....
```

Comment: Try to change the datatype before calculation: `cast(amount as decimal(28,6)) / 1000000`

Comment: Yes! That's it. Please enter as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the datatype to 6 fractional digits before calculation:

```
cast(amount as decimal(28,6)) / 1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with rules of such arithmetic operations. Refer to the [Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html) article.

Briefly:
INT / INT = INT
DEC(p, s) / DEC(p', s') = DEC(31, 31-p+s-s')

So, if you want to get DEC(31, X) on INT / INT, you may explicitly cast a numerator to DEC(31-X).
In your case (X=6):

```
> db2 describe dec(1, 25)/1000000
 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 484   DECIMAL               31, 6  1                                         1
```